# php Redis::hscan Retrieve all hashes with wildcard name and condition

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis

So, I have a heap (thousands) of hashes, with names like this:

```
state:city:street
```

And within each one is something like:

```
signId => 10,
damaged => 1
```

I essentially want to do some trickery that I am not sure is possible.

I want to get all values for `signId` but only if the `signId` entry exists but the `damaged` entry does not exist...

For all hashes that fall into the wildcard `state:city:*`

And all in PHP / Laravel / Predis

Comment: If there is no way to do this, is there a way to structure the way I use Redis so it is simpler?

Comment: How many keys do you have in your redis server ? it this going to be a one time execution or will you use it actively ?

Comment: It will get used hundreds of times per day. Lets say there will be up to 15000 keys/hashes/sets. But I only want to select the hashes, so less than 1000 of them at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in feature or a function to do them in redis. I don't recommend you to use `keys` in production. As it is mentioned on [redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys);

> `keys` should be used in production environment with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases.

I will recommend three options;

- `scan` is a better alternative to the `keys` since it doesn't block the server for a long time. On your application level you may execute the hash keys matching to your pattern and then using `HGET` (O(1)) two times and making comparison. `HGETALL` is also another option if your hash keys don't have many fields.
- Another option is to keep track of your hash keys matching a pattern in a separate set/list. Whenever you call `HMSET` or `HSET` you also push that key in a set/list. By keeping tracking of the keys, you no longer need to use `scan` later. You may just get them in a paginated way to execute related hash commands. As the recommendation one, this also require application level querying instead of data layer querying.
- Since you need to query with multiple conditions it may be better to keep them in a relational database(postgresql, mysql etc). Redis is good to serve your hashes, but when you need to query your hashes the way you want to query then it is better to re-model your data.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the keys first as `keys state:city:*`

Then, you will have to do `HGETALL state:city:{name}` one by one i.e in a loop.

Comment: I'd really rather not use KEYS as it is blocking. is there no other way?

Comment: Unfortunately, No